# What is wrong in this regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I am using this code for verifying full name.I expect users to enter a name like Abc def or Abc Def or Abc DEF etc...But with this i could not get the correct answer.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z] ?[A-Za-z]$/", $value) && !empty($value))
echo "NOT MATCHING";
else if(!empty($value))
echo "MATCHING";
```

Comment: What about my name: PeeHaa von Trappenhaus? BTW you only accept single letters

Comment: So because that is my name I am invalid? :(

Comment: @PeeHaa hehe you have an invalid name :p.

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way :

```
"/^[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)?$/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `+` to match also names longer than one character ;)

```
"/^[A-Za-z]+ ?[A-Za-z]+$/"
```

Answer (score 1):

The character don't repeat. It only allows on character before and after the space.

```
^[A-Za-z]+(\s)+?[A-Za-z]+$
```

remember that the pattern `^[A-Za-z] ?[A-Za-z]$` can match

```
JohnWoo
```

because space is optional.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a multiplier after your bracket statements.

Something like this would work better : `"/^[A-Za-z]+ ?[A-Za-z]+$/"`
Otherwise it means you're looking for a 1 caracter long string for each bracket statement. here with the `+` sign, it's *"one or longer"*.

Answer (score 0):

As name may have also a middle name, initial followed by period, or possible more names, you should go with regex pattern

```
/^[A-Za-z]+\.?(\s+[A-Za-z]+\.?)*$/
```

If you want to limit space between names just to one space-bar character, replace `\s+` with `[ ]`

Additionally, If you want to allow leading and/or trailing spaces, add `\s*` at the beginning and/or the end of pattern.

---

Example of match: *John W. Doe Jr.*